# How to make properly transaction and/or lock tables in MySQL for e-shop in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking

I would like to use transactions and/or locking tables in my e-shop, mainly to avoid order-id duplication (it is not only autoincrement ID).

**Now I have this scenario:**

```
1) cart submitted by user
2) check if all informations are correcly filled
3) lock tables with products, orders and discount cupons
4) begin transaction
-- try { --
5) update products stocks
6) mark discount cupon as used
7) get order-id (it is based on number of orders today)
8) save order
-- } catch { --
9a) rollback transaction
10a) unlock tables
-- } --
9b) commit transaction
10b) unlock tables
11) send mail and show thankfull message to user
```

**Q1:** I am wondering if this scenario is "correct" or there is a better way?

**Q2:** Do I need to lock tables when I use transactions? Beside not getting order-id duplicated, I would like to affect users and admins of e-shop as little as possible. I decided to use transaction because of making data consistent - for example, when products stocks are updated but saving order fail, it would be nice to rollback previous stocks numbers.

I appreciate all comments and recommendations guys.

Comment: No need to lock tables, otherwise ok. Transactions do lock the rows that are being modified.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask when should I use lock on tables? I can always use transaction or are here cases when it is inappropriate?

Comment: Lockin a table is like using a battle axe in an operating theatre instead of a scalpel. There are some database operations that require it, however, most of those would implicitly lock tables anyway. I reslly cannot think of any reason why you would use table locks during normal operation of a database.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, remove table locks, other wise fine.

You should pretty much never use explicit table locks. There may be some edge cases in provisioning scripts when its needed, but otherwise best if you forget they exist.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Last thing I wonder is that between point 2) and 4) there is a very small delay, but there is. I would like to be 100% sure ordered products are in stock which I check in point 2). Should I start transaction before point 2) (so immediatelly cart is submitted by user) or should I do some another check within current transaction, somewhere before point 5)? In my case it is very small chance, but more than that I wonder how large e-shops handle that, if they could have a several orderes within second.

Comment: As you update stock levels, `update  qty = qty - purchase .. where qty >= purchase`. Then look at rows affected to see if it could be taken away. If those fail you can rollback/out of stock error.